# calling a url via java return 404 while via chrome browser works fine

Tags: java, url, jersey, http-status-code-404

I have this code:

```
private CompleteRoutingResponseWrapper sendRoutingRequestString(String routingRequestUrl) {
    routingRequestUrl = urlUtils.getHttpUrl(routingRequestUrl);

    CompleteRoutingResponseWrapper answer = new CompleteRoutingResponseWrapper();
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    try {

        Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        response = client.execute(new HttpGet(routingRequestUrl));
        stopWatch.stop();

        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != 200) {
            answer.errorMsg = handleError(routingRequestUrl, response, statusCode);
            answer.completeRoutingResponse = new com.waze.routing.automation.dataModel.serverResponse.dto
                    .CompleteRoutingResponse();
        } else {
            String bodyAsString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            answer.completeRoutingResponse = handleSuccess(bodyAsString);
            answer.latency = stopWatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            handleErrorInBody(routingRequestUrl, answer, bodyAsString);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return answer;
}
```

I call this method with hundreds of urls.

for some of them I get sporadically 404.

however when I to to call these urls from the browser itself, I get OK response.

what can cause this? how can I stabilize my code?

It happens sporadically and not for all urls.

Comment: Could there be some User-Agent based filtering on their server?

Comment: @Sandeep no, because this happens sporadically and not for all urls. any other idea?